# Does read() causes the kernel device driver code to be executed?

Tags: operating-system, linux-device-driver, system-calls

Does **read()** system call causes the kernel device driver code to be executed? 
I mean, when I want to read files from disk or from any driver, I use read() system call. Is that system call must use driver code to complete this task?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by driver code? Do you mean the device driver code which is in the kernel?

Comment: @sks-15. indeed. I wonder if the device driver code should run in this situation.

Comment: Well, the code that queues up a request to the driver will run and, possibly, the driver will actually initiate the read.  The caller will, usually, be suspended, awaiting I/O completion interrupt and signal from the driver.

Comment: Depends.  Access to most devices is fully buffered.  If the system buffer has sufficient data to satisfy the user's **read()** request, then no actual I/O has to be performed, and the driver code is not involved in those cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the `read()` uses `standard file descriptors` to read files from fixed offsets in files and of fixed bytes. The `standard file descriptors` are not files on the disc, but rather associated with a different device, the terminal device. Hence the drivers must be in use for the files to be accessed.

See [man read](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man2/read.2.html) for its usage and `C` prototype.

For more info about file handling use [this](https://www.usna.edu/Users/cs/aviv/classes/ic221/s16/lec/21/lec.html) link, particularly the **"Reviewing Open Files"** section for your particular query.